# Fix div position between two heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that I want to keep `position: fixed` when scrolling between two points.
For example, it should remain fixed only between the height of it's container div

I've done the following:

```
$window.scroll(function(e) {
    pos = $('.container-element').height();
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $(scroll-element).css({
            position: 'relative',
        });
    } else {
        $(scroll-element).css({
            position: 'fixed',
        });
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't stop the `scroll-element` from becoming relative on reaching the end of the `container-element`. What should I do to achieve the intended behavior?

EDIT:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/09760d60/

Comment: Would a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) be possible?

Comment: Is `scroll-element` a custom HTML element? If so, it should be quoted as a string when you pass it to jQuery. Also, `var pos = ...`.

Comment: @doveyg, Added fiddle

Comment: So basically in your Fiddle, the black element should become `position:relative;` when any part of it becomes outside the grey element?

Comment: @JamieBarker Yep, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: I think it works, I have updated the fiddle after editing a few heights to demonstrate the principle. http://jsfiddle.net/09760d60/3/

Comment: That is because your test: scrollTop() > pos will **never become true**. If you put some console.log in your code you will see that when you reach the bottom of your scroll you will get the following values: pos(800) scrollTop(352). So your code says oke: if 800 > 352 then true. But it will always be **false** because the "scrollTop" will never be bigger than 800px

Comment: position fixed is relative to the browser window. Can not possible between two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You should remove fixed position when $(window).scrollTop() > containerHeight-childHeight

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    containerHeight = $('.container-element').height();
    childHeight = $(".scroll-element").height();


    if ($(window).scrollTop() > containerHeight-childHeight) {
        $('.scroll-element').removeClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('.scroll-element').addClass('fixed');
    }
}); 
});
```

Please check updated fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/1u991v1j/

Comment: Yes this is perfect solution.But as per question it can't possible between two end points make a component fixed.

Comment: As per question it seems he wants child div should not be fixed when scroll position reaches its container height.... :-)

Comment: This is pretty much what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check the top and bottom bounds of your container, and compare it with the top and bottom bounds of your scroll element :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        containerTop = $('.container-element').offset().top;
        containerBottom = $('.container-element').height()+$('.container-element').offset().top;
        scrollEl = $('.scroll-element').height();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= containerTop && $(window).scrollTop()+scrollEl <= containerBottom) {
            $('.scroll-element').css({
                "top":$(window).scrollTop()+"px"   
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/048b3m8m/)

---

- `$(window).scrollTop() < containerTop`: scroll element is at top of content
- `$(window).scrollTop()+scrollEl > containerBottom`: bottom of scroll element is at bottom of content
- If scroll element has to move, adjust its top property while being absolutelly positioned by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more robust to check the bottoms of the container and window, not the heights of the container and child.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    var $container = $('.container-element');
    var $scroll = $('.scroll-element');
    var containerBox = $container[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    $window.scroll(function(e) {
        var scrollBottom = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
        var canSeeContainerBottom = scrollBottom > containerBox.bottom;

        $scroll.css('position', canSeeContainerBottom ? 'relative' : 'fixed');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/09760d60/14/